# Position widgets in stack without overlapping

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a login screen with a logo on top. I want the login form to be exactly in the screen center (not in the center of the space below the logo). So far I managed to achieve that using `Stack`, roughly like this:

```
Stack(
   children: [
      Positioned(
        child: Logo(),
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
      ),
      Column(
          children: [LoginForm()],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      ),
   ],
)
```

In general, I am quite happy with how it looks, however, when the soft keyboard pops up, the visible screen size and the notion of the center change, the form moves up and overlaps with the logo. I know I can prevent widgets from resizing at all, but can I just allow the form move up only as long as it does not overlap with the logo?

Comment: Hi How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @VirendraVarma if I recall correct, it was enough to set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` in the wrapping `Scaffold`. In that case the keyboard overlaps with the form, but we decided it's good enough.

Comment: yes it's working thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ListView` instead of `Column` that will avoid overlapping with the logo and when keyboard opens, it will automatically scroll up the form. 
Also note that, once you use `ListView`, use `shrinkWrap: true` inside it, as it'll only occupy the space it needs.
Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ListView` does not seem to have vertical alignment. As such, it overlaps with the logo even without the keyboard. Do you mean using `ListView` in some different layout, e.g. without a `Stack`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the logo widget is positioned, updated the code.